# FusedLocationProvider return null

Tags: android, google-maps, null, android-fusedlocation

I used fusedlocation provider client for get device location.But if location setting off my phone and open location setting with locationServices. getSettingsClient fused location provider return null

```
 final Task<Location> locationTask = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        locationTask.addOnSuccessListener((Activity) context, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    lastKnownLocation = location;
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                    lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), Constants.DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                    HashMap<String, String> adressInfo = MapUtility.getAddressGeocoderObject(context, position);

                    MapUtility.moveCamera(context, map, position, Constants.DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                            adressInfo.get("addressFeatureName"), adressInfo.get("remainAdress"));


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

solved my problem when update fusedLocation provider

```
private void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10*1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10*1000);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

private void createLocationCallback(){
    locationCallback=new LocationCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
           //code here

        }
    };

}
```

and if location null update fused location provider

```
 public void getDeviceLocation() {
    try {
        final Task<Location> locationTask = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        locationTask.addOnSuccessListener((Activity) context, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    lastKnownLocation = location;
                    if(map==null){
                        Toast.makeText(context,"map null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                    lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), Constants.DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                    HashMap<String, String> adressInfo = MapUtility.getAddressGeocoderObject(context, position);

                    assert adressInfo != null;
                    MapUtility.moveCamera(context, map, position, Constants.DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                            adressInfo.get("addressFeatureName"), adressInfo.get("remainAdress"));

                } else {
                    createLocationRequest();
                    createLocationCallback();
                    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,locationCallback,Looper.myLooper());

                }


            }


        });

        locationTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(Constants.PlacesTag, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
            }
        });


    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```